# Maintain seperate git branches - One for heroku and another for github

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, github, git-branch

I have got a project in nodejs which is on github and deployed on heroku. In that project I use a few API keys and those keys are stored in `config.js` file which is ignored while pushing to github. But I need those files for deployment on heroku. So my problem is when ever I make any changes to push on github I have to ignore that `config.js` file and when I deploy on heroku I have to include those again in my branch. I am stuck in this viscous cycle.

Thank You

This is my second time asking question here. So if I did not follow any convention please tell so that I may edit for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, maintain three branches, `github`, `heroku`, and `orphan`.

In the `github` branch, write all your code (except the js file in question).

In the `orphan` branch, (created using `git branch branch_name --orphan`), add and commit the js file.

Every time you want to push to heroku, create a new branch out of github (`git checkout heroku && git reset --hard github`) and then merge the orphan branch (using `git merge orphan`).

Now you can push this branch to heroku.

Comment: what is "orphan"? I get `error: unknown option 'orphan'`

Answer (score 0):

You could juggle multiple branches to maintain your configuration file, but you might prefer using environment variables instead.

In your Heroku app administration, go to the "Config Variables" or the "Settings" tab. You likely have default variables set already.

Add your API keys, and you can access them in Node using process.env.ENV_VARIABLE where ENV_VARIABLE is the name you give the variable.

You can setup the same environment variables in the local development environment in your Virtual Host or in your System Environment Variables depending on your setup.

Checkout this article for more details about config vars: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars